# What is the relationship between field of view and focal length for fisheye?

Tags: focal-length, field-of-view, fisheye, projection

What is the relationship between the focal length and field of view for an equal-area ("equisolid") projection fisheye lens?  Alternatively, what is the relationship between the 180-degree image circle size and the focal length for such a lens?

Ultimately I want to find the field of view of a Tokina 10-17 mm fisheye zoom at focal lengths other than 10 mm on APS-C ([at 10 mm Tokina claims 180 degrees diagonally](http://www.tokinalens.com/tokina/products/atx/atx107afdxfisheye/)).

Answer (score 4):

[Michel Thoby's webpage](http://michel.thoby.free.fr/Fisheye_history_short/Projections/Fisheye_projection-models.html) has the following formula for the equal-area projection:

```
r = 2 f sin(θ/2)
```

where `r` is the distance from the centre in the projection plane of a point that is visible under angle `θ`.

[image]
<sup>([image source](http://michel.thoby.free.fr/Fisheye_history_short/Projections/Fisheye_projection-models.html))</sup>

For 10 mm focal length this gives `r = 2 * 10 mm * sin(π/2 / 2) = 14 mm` for the radius of the 180-degree image circle.  This roughly matches the half diagonal of APS-C sensors ([nominally 15 mm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APS-C)).  Diagonal fisheye lenses using this projection indeed all have ~ 10 mm focal length (Nikon 10.5 mm, Sigma 10 mm, Tokina 10-17 mm).

The reverse formula for calculating the field of view will be

```
FoV = 2 θ = arcsin(r / (2f))
```

where `r` is now the half-diagonal of the sensor.  For APS-C with r = 15 mm and f = 17 mm this gives 105 degrees, which matches Tokina's claim for 100 degrees at 17 mm.

We can also make a plot to show the field of view versus focal length for equal area projection fisheyes, and compare with rectilinear lenses.

[image]

Most current APS-C cameras have slightly smaller sensors with diagonals closer to 14 mm, so in practice the angle of view will be a bit less than what's shown on this graph.  Let's make another plot for the sensor size of an actual camera (Nikon D7100).

[image]

Note 1: This is not valid for all fisheye lenses. Some use different projections, such as the Samyang 8 mm, which is said to be closer to [stereographic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection).  [The page linked above](http://michel.thoby.free.fr/Fisheye_history_short/Projections/Fisheye_projection-models.html) has a lot of information on various projections.

Note 2: Some projection software [such as PanoTools](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/Fisheye_Projection.html) use a more general projection formula of `r = k1 f sin(θ/k2)` where `k1` and `k2` are found empirically (from measurements) for different lenses.  [This page](http://web.archive.org/web/20160121222300/http://www.pierretoscani.com/echo_fisheyes_english.html) shows the results of such measurements.

---

Originally I made a mistake and forgot the one half factor from the sine function, which caused a wrong result and confused me.  Instead of deleting the question I'm posting this as community wiki anyway as others may find it useful.

Comment: Why make this answer CW? It's a perfectly valid answer, and with a little editing, the original question itself is a good one. I couldn't find another question here that exactly applied. I say un-CW the answer, and get your well-deserved rep

Comment: @scottbb Well, yesterday I made an embarrassing mistake when I forgot that 1/2 factor from inside of the sine (see my comment on the other answer).  If I had found that mistake earlier, I would have deleted the question ... I was worried about backlash.  I don't care much about reputation score any more, so CW is okay.

Comment: What formula are you using for the rectilinear lens?  The projection mapping function is image height = focal length * tan (angle off axis)
Your rectilinear curve looks mostly, well, linear, and it should be blowing up  starting around 80 degrees.  The formula image height = focal length * (angle off axis) is not the formula for a rectilinear lens, but is the formula "weak fisheyes" use.

Comment: @Brandon The inverse of what you mentioned:  `2 arctan(r/f)`, where `r = 15 mm` is the half-diagonal of APS-C.

Comment: Here is another page that covers these formulas: http://www.bobatkins.com/photography/technical/field_of_view.html

Answer (score -1):

The angle of view calculation requires trigonometry:
This is the formula I use in Excel.

=((ATAN((d/2/f)))x180/9.8596

d=the dimension of the frame
35mm full frame 24mm height by 36mm length diagonal 42.36mm
f=focal length
x=multiply

10mm = 100⁰ height – 121⁰ length 127⁰ diagonal

12mm = 90⁰ height – 113⁰ length 120⁰ diagonal

14mm = 81⁰ height – 104⁰ length 114⁰ diagonal

17mm = 70⁰ height – 93⁰ length 104⁰ diagonal

For the compact (APS-C) 16mm height by 24mm length by 30mm diagonal

10mm = 77⁰ height – 100⁰ length 110⁰ diagonal

12mm = 67⁰ height – 90⁰ length 100⁰ diagonal

14mm = 60⁰ height – 81⁰ length 82⁰ diagonal

17mm = 50⁰ height –70⁰ length 81⁰ diagonal

Comment: What you wrote is valid for a rectilinear lens, i.e. for projection through a point.  It also needs a factor of 2 in front of the arc-tangent.  But this is not a rectilinear lens, far from it.  Hence my question.

Comment: Then I don't know the math sorry!

Comment: I found [this page](http://michel.thoby.free.fr/Fisheye_history_short/Projections/Fisheye_projection-models.html) which claims that the distance `r` for a point from the image centre is `r = 2*f*sin(θ/2)`, where `f` is the focal length and `θ` is angle measures from the optical axis for that point.  But it doesn't add up.  Equal-area projection lenses that have a 180 degree diagonal FoV tend to have ~10 mm focal length (like this Tokina or the Nikon 10.5 mm).  According to this formula they'd have a 20 mm radius 180 deg  image circle. But the half-diagonal of APS-C is only 15 mm...